# How to generate word suffix using Tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

We are working with Tensorflow. We have a very large dataset of words, brands and so on. We are trying to generate suffixes for words. For instance, give 'real' may give 'realtor', 'really', 'realestate', ... In our dataset, each word is separated by \n.

We have tried several things so far, but it does not seem to produce adequate results. It seems to me that this is a fairly simple task that should be solved

The basic idea we are working on is adapting [char-rnn-tensorflow](https://github.com/sherjilozair/char-rnn-tensorflow). We have simply changed the sampling to sample (with weighted random probabilities) until a carriage return is sampled. We kept the original implementation, with rnn_decoder and sequence_loss_by_example and used rnn as model.

So far, we haven't obtained good samples, almost random ones and sometimes suffixes but without any relation to the beginning of our word (real -> realstation). It is possible that it comes from the fact that this implementation do not separate words, so we would need something more simple ?

What technologies would you use for such a task ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, we have been able to obtain good results by carefully tuning the parameters of the network and applying temperature to the results to get some good suggestions. The sequence length was very important during training.